# Error Exception message: The product's required option(s) weren't entered. Make sure the options are entered and try again. Magento 2

Tags: product, magento2.3, addtocart, frontend-error

> Hi @all actually i am facing `Error Exception message: The product's
>   required option(s) weren't entered. Make sure the options are entered
>   and try again. Magento 2` error while Products  addToCart
>   programmatically.
>
> And also addProduct() function making problem here.

```
#1 /var/www/html/url/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart->addProduct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
```

Please check code below:

```
<?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\AddProduct;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 
    use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;

    class AddItems extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        protected $formKey;   
        protected $cart;
        protected $product;
        protected $messageManager;
        protected $checkoutSession;
        protected $productRepository; 
        protected $redirect;
        protected $objectManager;
        protected $_productCreate;
        protected $customerSession;
        protected $serializer;

        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productCreate,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        SerializerInterface $serializer
        ) {
            $this->formKey = $formKey;
            $this->cart = $cart;
            $this->product = $product;      
            $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
            $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
            $this->redirect = $redirect;
            $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
            $this->_productCreate = $productCreate;
            $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
            $this->serializer = $serializer;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute() { 

                $product_price = 100;
                $product_id = 109;      
                $params = array(
                        'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                        'product_id' => $product_id, //product Id
                        'qty'   => 1 //quantity of product                
                        );      

                $customOptions =                                                
                    [
                        "option_id" => 10, // assign option Id
                        "option_value" => "Quaterly" // here set selected option item Id
                    ];

                $_product = $this->product->create()->load($product_id); 

                $_product->addCustomOption('additional_data',$this->serializer->serialize($customOptions)); //assigning custom options with products                    
                $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
                $productItem = $this->getProductQuote($_product);
                $productItem->setCustomPrice($product_price);
                $productItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($product_price);   
                $this->cart->save();
        }

        public function getProductQuote($product){
            $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();        
            $cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);        
            return $cartItems;
        }


}
```

If anyone understand the problem please help me.Thanks in Advance...!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct `params` format is like below:

```
$params = [
    'form_key' => <form_key>,
    'product' => <product_id>,
    'qty' => <quantity>,
    'options' => [
        <option_id_1> => <option_value_id_1>,
        <option_id_2> => <option_value_id_2>,
        <option_id_x> => <option_value_id_x>,
    ],
];
```

Your `params` array format does not implements the default rule. It should looks like this:

```
$params = [
    'form_Key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
    'product' => '109',
    'qty' => '1',
    'options' => [
        '10' => 'Quarterly',
    ],
];
```

The complete code should be like this:

```
$productId = 109;

$product = $this->product->create()->load($product_id);
$params = [
    'form_Key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
    'product' => $productId,
    'qty' => '1',
    'options' => [
        '10' => 'Quarterly',
    ],
];

$this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$this->cart->save();
```

Comment: thanks for perfect answer.